# How do you change the default shell for ALL USERS to bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, adduser

I want every new user from now on to have bash as their shell by default.

I know that to change your own shell to bash, you would use the command "chsh -s /bin/bash", but how do I automatically set all future users' shell to bash by default?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**adduser**

The `adduser` defaults file is `/etc/adduser.conf`. The default shell defined by the `DSHELL` variable is `/bin/bash` by default.

**useradd**

Most likely you don't need this because useradd is a very low-level utility, and it's hardly ever used directly.

If you use useradd, edit the `/etc/default/useradd` skeleton file (don't forget to make a backup though).

Set the `SHELL` variable to `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`.

Now every time you use `useradd` to add a new user `bash` is automatically their default shell.

**Already existing users**

If you want to change the shell of already existing users you have to edit the `/etc/passwd` file (please make sure to back have a backup of it).

Here is a description of the columns

1. login name
2. optional encrypted password
3. numerical user ID
4. numerical group ID
5. user name or comment field
6. user home directory
7. optional user command interpreter

In that order separated by colons (:) like this.

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

For more information about that file consult the man page `man 5 passwd`.

Comment: I think a safer way to change another user's shell would be something like `sudo -u $USER chsh -s $SHELL`.

Comment: @JackO'Connor you should post that as an answer as well.

Comment: This does not seem to be working in Ubuntu 16.04. Does anyone know the fix.

Answer (score 38):

As Octavian pointed out, the way to change the defaults depends on the way you're creating the user. I tried creating a new user through my Gnome Settings just now, and it seems to follow `/etc/default/useradd`, so that might be your best bet. For existing users, the safest way to change someone else's login shell is with **usermod**:

```
usermod -s /bin/bash $USERNAME
```

If you're not root, you'll need to **sudo** that. An alternative is to **sudo** into the user you want to modify and just run **chsh**, like this:

```
sudo -u $USERNAME chsh -s /bin/bash
```

It's best to avoid editing `/etc/passwd` by hand, because a mistake in there could break all sorts of things.

Answer (score 4):

If you actually want all users on the server to have bash (which was the question actually asked), you can run the command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

And then choose NOT dash. As explained in this answer,

[How Can I Make /bin/sh point to /bin/bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064773/how-can-i-make-bin-sh-point-to-bin-bash)

Not only does that set bash as the default shell, but repoints sh and the man pages correctly.

Hope this helps.