# How to control cursor in xfce4 LXTerminal?

Tags: xfce4-terminal, 14.04

I've just installed xfce4 lightweight desktop on 14.04 server but the console and LXTerminal do not works as I expected when using arrow keys to control the cursor.  When I press an arrow key it appears that a representation of the key code is output to the console rather than acted on.  The OS was just installed and neither console nor terminal worked this way in the previous 14.04.x installation (with lightweight gnome).

The arrow keys don't work in Byobu Terminal either.

How do I force the terminal (and console) to recognize the navigation keys?

EDIT
The reason is that on boot the shell is sh (dash), which is about one tenth the size of bash.

The as yet unanswered questions are how to I set the system shell to bash and should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in my edit above, the machine boots to /bin/sh - dash.  To assign existing users to bash or set bash for new users see [How do you change the default shell for ALL USERS to bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28969/how-do-you-change-the-default-shell-for-all-users-to-bash)